# how to create a macvlan network interface in the same network as the host?

Tags: interface, lxc

I am new to unix/linux systems and I am trying to bring up a `macvlan` interface in the same network as the host e.g. if the `eth0` of host has ip `1.2.3.4` I want to create an interface having an ip `1.2.3.xx/24` whenever I do that entries in the routing table change and the whole network connectivity is lost.

Can anyone help me?

I added the following in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto macvlan0`
iface macvlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.142
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: You probably noticed already, but if you wish to configureyour virtual interface via /etc/netork/interfaces, you will need to add to its stanza:  *pre-up ip li add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan* and*post-down ip link del dev mac0*, the two commands that create and destroy the virtual interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `dnsmasq` if it isn't installed and re-try. Post your results

Create the interface from the command line to test.

`ip link add virtual0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge`

`ip address add 10.10.10.88/24 broadcast 10.10.10.255 dev virtual0`

substitute the IPs in your environment.

Comment: Probably worth noticing that you can also use DHCP; *i.e.* no static IP: *ip li add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan*, then *ip link set dev mac0 up*, and lastly *dhclient -v mac0*.

Comment: What's the purpose of dnsmasq there?